# Schedule mail R/Knitr reports

Tags: r, email, report, knitr, schedule

I need to schedule some monthly reports that need to be sent by email.
I love the flexibility of R for analisys and data manipulation and even if not very experienced with knitr I would manage to produce the reports I need. My problem is with the mailing bit. What would be the best workflow to achieve this?

Comment: `sendmailR` package and cron jobs spring to mind

Comment: If you're a windows user the task scheduler could do this in combination with a number of email packages for R.

Comment: check out this gist https://gist.github.com/hadley/5707759 by @hadley on how to use postmarkapp to send emails. they have a free account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never done this kind of job but if I have to do,  I would not use an R package to send mail. I would use something like [Mutt](http://www.mutt.org/doc/man_page.html) (available [on windows](http://www.oocities.org/win32mutt/win32.html) also) Mail User Agent to send my report as an attachment. Do I would create a batch **mailsender.(sh|bat)**  that launch this R script **mailsender.R**:

```
   source('genreport.R')  ## here you will call for example knit2pdf('myreport.Rnw')
   writeLines(message,p<-pipe('mutt -s mySubject -a myreport.pdf -- mail@mail.com'))
   close(p)
```

Your batch/shell script contain :

```
  Rscript path_to_mailsender_\mailsender.R
```

Finally you can use **cron** or **windows scheduler** ( I don't know for mac) to schedule monthly this job.

For example using cron , you need somthing like this to send you report at 8pm on the first of every month:

```
       0 8 1 * * /path/to/mailsender.sh
```